# Refresh rate stuck at 93Hz on Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: nvidia, upgrade

Until a few days back my refresh rate was 75Hz. Now it's stuck at 93Hz. My monitor doesn't even support 93Hz. I use a Nvidia GT 710 card. I'm unable to upgrade the system through software updates.

[image: screenshot of display settings]

Comment: Why can't you update your system? This speaks to a much larger problem. Can you elaborate? What else changed between now and the last time you could set the correct refresh rate?

Comment: See nvidia-settings to adjust the refresh rate for nVidia cards using a 3rd party driver.